# hide debug information in dev environnement

Tags: symfony4

I'am working on web app with symfony4.

by default in developement environnement Symfony catches all the exceptions and displays a special exception page with lots of debug information to help you discover the root problem.my question is to know how can I desable or hide details informations

Comment: Switch to prod environment in your `.env` file. The only reason for dev environment is to see all of those things you are trying to hide.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to disable the Profiler Debug Bar on the Bottom Screen you can do this with editing for the DEV Environment:

```
# config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml
web_profiler:
  toolbar: false # set to false to disable
```

As stated on the comment by ehymel you should want this information if you are working on the DEV Environment.

The only use case i can imagine is when disabling this is for an automatic test run while still having the dev environment on.